# In a probability generating function, what exactly is the parameter for G(z)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

For instance, given $\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}  
   \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
G(z) = \E z^X$, what exactly is $z$? and also what does the generating function actually give you? Because it states that it is returning the expected value of $z^X$ but how exactly is that helpful/what does it mean?

Comment: $z$ here is a dummy variable and among other things, the probability generating function if it exists gives you probabilities (as the name suggests) and moments of the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Please do not [cross post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/371461/119261). This is against SE rules in general.

Comment: Apologies, I intended to post here and delete the other but I couldn't find the delete function on the other page

Answer (score 1):

The variable $z$ is just a dummy variable, as mentioned in the comments.  Some textbooks also use $\mathbb{E}\left [ s^{k} \right ]$.

The probability generating function has many important properties.  For a random variable $X$,
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ X \right ] = G'\left ( 1 \right )$$
and 
$$\text{Var}(X)= G''(1)+G'(1)-\left [ G'(1) \right ]^2.$$
Another interesting property is that it is related to moment generating functions from the fact that 
$$G_{X}(e^{t})=M_{X}(t).$$
Probability generating functions are important in stochastic processes like branching processes and extinction probabilities.